# PyParsing OnlyOnce

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

I'm parsing a file with pyparsing. It works fine but I think the processing time can be improved by using the OnlyOnce class instead of OneOrMore at the "parse_file = pp.OneOrMore(dbuPerMicron | diearea | components) + pp.StringEnd()" line. After the components section of the def file there are other sections that are useless to me and the parser takes a long time to finish due to these lines. By using OnlyOnce in the pase_file it gives: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'searchString'".

I appreciate any suggestions.

```
def parse_def(self):
        ifile = open("path_to.def",'r')
        def_string = ifile.read()
        ifile.close()

        EOL              = pp.LineEnd().suppress()
        linebreak        = pp.Suppress(";" + pp.LineEnd())
        identifier       = pp.Word(pp.alphanums+'_!<>/')
        number           = pp.Word(pp.nums + ".")
        word             = pp.Word(pp.alphas)

        # UNITS DISTANCE MICRONS
        dbuPerMicron_id  = pp.Keyword('UNITS DISTANCE MICRONS')
        dbuPerMicron     = pp.Group(dbuPerMicron_id + number('UnitsPerMicron')).setResultsName('dbuPerMicron')

        # DIEAREA
        diearea_id  = pp.Keyword('DIEAREA')
        diearea     = pp.Group(pp.Suppress(diearea_id) + pp.OneOrMore(pp.Suppress('(') + number + number + pp.Suppress(')')) + pp.Suppress(linebreak)).setResultsName('DIEAREA')

        # COMPONENTS
        components_id    = pp.Keyword('COMPONENTS')
        end_components   = pp.Keyword("END COMPONENTS").suppress()

        begin_comp       = pp.Keyword('-')
        ws_comp          = pp.Keyword('+')  # parameter division in componentes
        comment          = pp.Keyword('#')
        comp_name        = identifier
        compName         = (comp_name('comp_name') + identifier('cell')).setResultsName('compName')
        EEQMASTER        = (pp.Suppress(ws_comp) + identifier('EEQMASTER') + identifier('macroName')).setResultsName('EEQMASTER')

        SOURCE           = (pp.Suppress(ws_comp) + identifier('SOURCE') + identifier('source_type')).setResultsName('SOURCE')

        PLACEMENT_ids    = pp.Keyword('FIXED') | pp.Keyword('COVER') | pp.Keyword('PLACED') | pp.Keyword('UNPLACED')
        PLACEMENT_coord  = pp.Suppress('(') + number('placement_x') + number('placement_y') + pp.Suppress(')')
        PLACEMENT_orient = word('orientation')
        PLACEMENT        = PLACEMENT_ids + pp.ZeroOrMore(PLACEMENT_coord + PLACEMENT_orient)
        PLACEMENT        = (pp.Suppress(ws_comp) + PLACEMENT).setResultsName('PLACEMENT')

        HALO             = (pp.Suppress(ws_comp) + pp.Keyword('HALO') + pp.ZeroOrMore(pp.Keyword('SOFT')) + number('haloL') + number('haloB') + number('haloR') + number('haloT')).setResultsName('HALO')

        ROUTEHALO        = (pp.Suppress(ws_comp) + pp.Keyword('ROUTEHALO') + number('rhaloDist') + identifier('rhaloMinLayer') + identifier('rhaloMaxLayer')).setResultsName('ROUTEHALO')

        WEIGHT           = (pp.Suppress(ws_comp) + pp.Keyword('WEIGHT') + number('weight')).setResultsName('WEIGHT')

        REGION           = (pp.Suppress(ws_comp) + pp.Keyword('REGION') + identifier('region')).setResultsName('REGION')

        PROPERTY         = (pp.Suppress(ws_comp) + pp.Keyword('PROPERTY') + identifier('propName') + identifier('propVal')).setResultsName('PROPERTY')

        subcomponent     = pp.Group(pp.Suppress(begin_comp)
                                  + pp.OneOrMore(compName)
                                  + pp.ZeroOrMore(EEQMASTER)
                                  + pp.ZeroOrMore(SOURCE)
                                  + pp.OneOrMore(PLACEMENT)
                                  + pp.ZeroOrMore(HALO)
                                  + pp.ZeroOrMore(ROUTEHALO)
                                  + pp.ZeroOrMore(WEIGHT)
                                  + pp.ZeroOrMore(REGION)
                                  + pp.ZeroOrMore(PROPERTY)
                                  + pp.Suppress(linebreak)).setResultsName('subcomponents', listAllMatches=True)

        components       = pp.Group(pp.Suppress(components_id) + number('numComps') + pp.Suppress(linebreak)
                                  + pp.OneOrMore(subcomponent )
                                  + pp.Suppress(end_components)).setResultsName('components')


        dbuPerMicron.setParseAction(self.handle_dbuPerMicron)
        diearea.setParseAction(self.handle_diearea)
        components.setParseAction(self.handle_components)

        parse_file       = pp.OneOrMore(dbuPerMicron | diearea | components) + pp.StringEnd()
        # parse_file       = pp.OnlyOnce(dbuPerMicron | diearea | components) + pp.StringEnd()  # It doesn't work

        return parse_file.searchString(def_string)
```

Example of a def file grammar:

```
Grammar:
[UNITS DISTANCE MICRONS dbuPerMicron;]

[DIEAREA ptpt [pt] ... ;]

COMPONENTS numComps ;
        [– compName modelName
        [+ EEQMASTER macroName]
        [+ SOURCE {NETLIST | DIST | USER | TIMING}]
        [+ {FIXED pt orient | COVER pt orient | PLACED pt orient | UNPLACED} ]
        [+ HALO [SOFT] leftbottomrighttop]
        [+ ROUTEHALO haloDistminLayermaxLayer]
        [+ WEIGHT weight]
        [+ REGION regionName]
        [+ PROPERTY {propName propVal} ...]...;] ...
END COMPONENTS
```

Example of a def file:

```
VERSION 5.7 ;
DIVIDERCHAR "/" ;
BUSBITCHARS "[]" ;
DESIGN c1908 ;
UNITS DISTANCE MICRONS 2000 ;

PROPERTYDEFINITIONS
    COMPONENTPIN designRuleWidth REAL ;
    DESIGN FE_CORE_BOX_LL_X REAL 0.000 ;
    DESIGN FE_CORE_BOX_UR_X REAL 23.425 ;
    DESIGN FE_CORE_BOX_LL_Y REAL 0.000 ;
    DESIGN FE_CORE_BOX_UR_Y REAL 19.600 ;
END PROPERTYDEFINITIONS

DIEAREA ( 0 0 ) ( 46850 39200 ) ;

COMPONENTS 248 ;
- U293 NOR2_X1 + PLACED ( 6080 0 ) N
 ;
- U294 FA_X1 + PLACED ( 0 0 ) N
 ;
- U295 NAND2_X1 + PLACED ( 4560 5600 ) N
 ;
- U296 FA_X1 + PLACED ( 20520 2800 ) N
 ;
- U297 NAND2_X1 + PLACED ( 26600 2800 ) N
 ;
- U298 NAND2_X1 + PLACED ( 27740 2800 ) N
 ;
- U299 NAND2_X1 + PLACED ( 22800 8400 ) N
 ;
- U300 NOR2_X1 + PLACED ( 25460 5600 ) N
 ;
- U301 HA_X1 + PLACED ( 33440 5600 ) N
 ;
- U540 INV_X1 + PLACED ( 760 28000 ) N
 ;
END COMPONENTS

PINS 58 ;
- N1 + NET N1 + DIRECTION INPUT + USE SIGNAL
  + LAYER metal3 ( -70 0 ) ( 70 140 )
And more thousands of lines that are useless to me.
```

Comment: OnlyOnce is a decorator for parse actions, not a parser element type. By using `searchString`, pyparsing will parse the whole file, a character at a time looking for possible matches, and it cannot really know ahead of time when it has found everything of interest.  You have a bit more control if you use `scanString` instead - it returns a generator, so you can process as many or as few matches as you like and then stop.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Paul. I used searchString because I had trouble using scanString. When using the last the parser gave an error saying that 'X' character was expected at the beginning of the file, but I want to ignore many characters at the beginning. By parsing a simple character chain, like the hello world example in the pyparsing website, scanString works fine. I think I'm missing something. So, back to searchString, I thought that there was ZeroOrMore, OneOrMore and OnlyOnce (the parsed would stop after the first occurrence). Anyway, I will take another look at the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If creating a parser in its own method, I try to just do the parser definition and return that, and have the caller responsible for applying the parser to the input string. This simplifies the call interface to the `parser()` method, and makes it much easier to test in isolation.

I changed your `parse()` method to `parser()` and wrapped it in a dummy `X` class, but left the contents almost verbatim, just changing your final parsing statement to:

```
    return dbuPerMicron | diearea | components
```

Then I used this code to run the parser against an arbitrarily long sample (your posted sample, plus 10,000,000 random characters, including spaces and newlines):

```
parser = X().parser()

# accumulate results using scanString
results = []
for t, s, e in parser.scanString(sample):
    results.append(t)
    # BUG! (sorry)
    # if len(t) == 3:
    if len(results) == 3:
        break

# use builtin sum() function to merge all the parsed results into one
results = sum(results)

# or here is the same code as the above loop using islice to do the
# range checking for us
from itertools import islice
results = sum(t for t, s, e in islice(parser.scanString(sample), 0, 3))

# what did we get?
print(results.dump())
```

Creating the 10 million character bit was the most time-consuming task, but the parsing was able to stop after having parsed the 3 relevant segments. I wrote out the explicit looping using `scanString`, but with `itertools.islice`, you can collapse it down to one line.

The output from `results.dump()` looks like (long list lines are snipped for posting brevity):

```
[['UNITS DISTANCE MICRONS', '2000'], ['0', '0', ...
- DIEAREA: ['0', '0', '46850', '39200']
- components: ['248', ['U293', 'NOR2_X1', 'PLACED', '6080', ...
  - numComps: '248'
  - subcomponents: [['U293', 'NOR2_X1', 'PLACED', '6080', ... 
    [0]:
      ['U293', 'NOR2_X1', 'PLACED', '6080', '0', 'N']
      - PLACEMENT: ['PLACED', '6080', '0', 'N']
      - cell: 'NOR2_X1'
      - compName: ['U293', 'NOR2_X1']
      - comp_name: 'U293'
      - orientation: 'N'
      - placement_x: '6080'
      - placement_y: '0'
    [1]:
      ['U294', 'FA_X1', 'PLACED', '0', '0', 'N']
      - PLACEMENT: ['PLACED', '0', '0', 'N']
      - cell: 'FA_X1'
      - compName: ['U294', 'FA_X1']
      - comp_name: 'U294'
      - orientation: 'N'
      - placement_x: '0'
      - placement_y: '0'
    [2]:
      ['U295', 'NAND2_X1', 'PLACED', '4560', '5600', 'N']
      - PLACEMENT: ['PLACED', '4560', '5600', 'N']
      - cell: 'NAND2_X1'
      - compName: ['U295', 'NAND2_X1']
      - comp_name: 'U295'
      - orientation: 'N'
      - placement_x: '4560'
      - placement_y: '5600'
    [3]:
      ['U296', 'FA_X1', 'PLACED', '20520', '2800', 'N']
      - PLACEMENT: ['PLACED', '20520', '2800', 'N']
      - cell: 'FA_X1'
      - compName: ['U296', 'FA_X1']
      - comp_name: 'U296'
      - orientation: 'N'
      - placement_x: '20520'
      - placement_y: '2800'
    [4]:
      ['U297', 'NAND2_X1', 'PLACED', '26600', '2800', 'N']
      - PLACEMENT: ['PLACED', '26600', '2800', 'N']
      - cell: 'NAND2_X1'
      - compName: ['U297', 'NAND2_X1']
      - comp_name: 'U297'
      - orientation: 'N'
      - placement_x: '26600'
      - placement_y: '2800'
    [5]:
      ['U298', 'NAND2_X1', 'PLACED', '27740', '2800', 'N']
      - PLACEMENT: ['PLACED', '27740', '2800', 'N']
      - cell: 'NAND2_X1'
      - compName: ['U298', 'NAND2_X1']
      - comp_name: 'U298'
      - orientation: 'N'
      - placement_x: '27740'
      - placement_y: '2800'
    [6]:
      ['U299', 'NAND2_X1', 'PLACED', '22800', '8400', 'N']
      - PLACEMENT: ['PLACED', '22800', '8400', 'N']
      - cell: 'NAND2_X1'
      - compName: ['U299', 'NAND2_X1']
      - comp_name: 'U299'
      - orientation: 'N'
      - placement_x: '22800'
      - placement_y: '8400'
    [7]:
      ['U300', 'NOR2_X1', 'PLACED', '25460', '5600', 'N']
      - PLACEMENT: ['PLACED', '25460', '5600', 'N']
      - cell: 'NOR2_X1'
      - compName: ['U300', 'NOR2_X1']
      - comp_name: 'U300'
      - orientation: 'N'
      - placement_x: '25460'
      - placement_y: '5600'
    [8]:
      ['U301', 'HA_X1', 'PLACED', '33440', '5600', 'N']
      - PLACEMENT: ['PLACED', '33440', '5600', 'N']
      - cell: 'HA_X1'
      - compName: ['U301', 'HA_X1']
      - comp_name: 'U301'
      - orientation: 'N'
      - placement_x: '33440'
      - placement_y: '5600'
    [9]:
      ['U540', 'INV_X1', 'PLACED', '760', '28000', 'N']
      - PLACEMENT: ['PLACED', '760', '28000', 'N']
      - cell: 'INV_X1'
      - compName: ['U540', 'INV_X1']
      - comp_name: 'U540'
      - orientation: 'N'
      - placement_x: '760'
      - placement_y: '28000'
- dbuPerMicron: ['UNITS DISTANCE MICRONS', '2000']
  - UnitsPerMicron: '2000'
```

For items that you know will be integers or reals, you might use the expressions for `integer` and `real` (or just `number` which will match all the numeric forms) defined in `pyparsing.pyparsing_common`; these expressions will use a fast Regex for the parsing, and convert the result to the right Python type at parse time, so that you don't have to do this conversion later.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I did something similar leaving the code intact but separating the original file in two portions, one with all the sections that I need and the other with sections that I may need in the future, but now is garbage. I did this to parse in parallel, in this case using 2 processes only. I will post an answer with the alternative. I will of course test your implementation as well. Thank you again.

Comment: Paul, if I separate each section to parse in different methods and len(t) is always 1 for each call. Do I still have to use the for loop?

Comment: Gah, a bug!  Should be `len(results)`.

The for loop is what advances the scanString generator forward to the next match.

Comment: Paul, using your implementation with 1 for loop for the parser and  "return dbuPerMicron | diearea | components" it takes more than 3 minutes. If I separate the "components" in another method and call using 2 for loops, one for "return dbuPerMicron | diearea" and the other for "return components" it takes ~1min. Any suggestion? PS: I placed the "components" content at the end of the file.